# Simple Product Price for configurable product

Tags: configurable-product, ce-1.9.1.0

I am currently using Magento version 1.9.1, therefore I can't really use this plugin which does exactly what I want: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html

Is there a plugin (paid or free) that works for 1.9.1 and I can use it so when you select an option while on a configurable product, it fetches the SKU, price, images and description of the SIMPLE product? Also its very important for special prices to work, because for example I have a simple product that has different prices for Silver, Gold and VIP members so depending on what group the user is in should receive the correct price from the simple product price table when selecting an option.

Hope I was clear and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about changing the description, but the image should change with the selection automatically unless I am mistaken.  We're currently using this extension for the price part: http://www.best4mage.com/configurable-products-use-simple-price.html

I do not work for Best4Mage, nor am I getting paid to post this here.  I also don't use more than one simple price, so this might not work in your case "out of the box"

Answer (score 0):

Fate? Old question bumped by community, but as it is, I just worked on this for a client.

Have a look at this: https://www.ayasoftware.com/magento-simple-product-pricing

Works very well, and support was awesome. Client needed some tweaks to accommodate one of their sites, and the support sorted it out pronto, with some custom code, and a patch we can then apply to add the custom change.